# Combining PHP Variables

Tags: php

I've the following code:

```
if ($type == 'unit'){
$item_title = $result["title"];
}
elseif ($type == 'message'){
$item_title = $result["description"];
}
    // all should combine unit and message
elseif ($type == 'all'){
$item_title = $result["description"]
    $item_title .= $result["title"];
}

if (stripos( $item_title, $filter ) !== false || stripos( $item_title, $filter ) !== false)
```

How can I combine the unit and message results in the `elseif ($type == all)` statement?

Comment: Until now it is still not clear what is the situation and what is the question. If you wanted to combine the description and title as strings then you where successful. (congratulations) Btw. when you ask questions try not to start your post with code and also have the code being the smallest part. Otherwise smart people will not even read what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, is this what you want?

```
elseif ($type == 'all'){
    $item_title = $result["description"] . $result["title"];
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an associative array to store both....

```
elseif ($type == 'all') {
    $item_title = array(
                    'description' => $result["description"],
                    'title' => $result["title"]
                  );
}
```

You can then access them with `$item_title['description']` and `$item_title['title']`.

If you need to determine if `$item_title` is an array or not, use [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php).